# Unwanted Auto login on LAN

Tags: support, status-norepro, auto-login

We have a LAN which shares a common WAN IP address. My friend logged in into StackOverflow with his login from his PC. He sent a link of a question to me to check it. I opened it in incognito window of Google chrome and I found to be automatically logged in into StackOverflow with my friends account in my PC. Is that caused because of the common WAN IP address for the entire LAN? If so it's a big issue. Any of my friend can get logged in into my account automatically if he is in this LAN and I sent a question link to him.

Comment: "I feel it to be a security hole." Sure looks like it. But it's a security hole in your network infrastructure, not in our site.

Comment: @balpha : i checked with other websites, why dont they show this issue, why this "your so called site" only show this ? please answer me

Comment: @prashu132: We cannot see your network setup. What we *can* see is that ip addresses do not factor into authentication. If it did, I'd be constantly disconnected as I travel.

Comment: Am I you guy's enemy? Giving these much negative voting makes feel like that. I am not complaining to you, i'm just informing you that such an issue happened. Who knows whether its really your side issue or not. StackOverflow makers are not the supreme developers of the world so that they wont make mistakes.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences Relax. We know you're informing us of an issue. We're telling you that we can't determine anything on our side to be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Down votes on support requests usually seem quite silly to me too, but don't take them personally.

Comment: I have to agree with @TimPost here; I *guess* the down votes mean, "Your report does not make sense to me and I think your conclusion is wrong", but I don't see a reason from the question itself to down vote. (my opinion!) that said, some of the subsequent comments might have earned a couple of the down votes. (understanding, as I do, that some of the DV's possibly came before the comments)

Answer (score 13):

No, that's not possible. Your IP address is never taken into account for authentication, let alone the only thing to authenticate you.

What *is* possible is that your WAN uses a faulty proxy to cache Stack Overflow responses.

Comment: not sure about that, i'm not a network guy so donno much about proxies its managed by seperate team and i dont have access to that

Comment: So, check with the system administrator.

Comment: @prashu132: If this is the case you may see the same effect on other sites that require authentication maybe - try looking for those.

Comment: i didnt have problem with other sites, i checked it first as soon as this issue occured.